# I want to save more texts in a file.data using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pickle
import random

guessesTaken = 0

print('Hello! What is your name?')
name = raw_input()
number = random.randint(1, 20)
print('Well, ' + name + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')

while guessesTaken < 6:
    print('Take a guess.') # There are four spaces in front of print.
    guess = raw_input()
    guess = int(guess)

    guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1

    if guess < number:
        print('Your guess is too low.') # There are eight spaces in front of print.

    if guess > number:
        print('Your guess is too high.')

    if guess == number:
        break

if guess == number:
    guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
    print('Good job, ' + name + '! You guessed my number in ' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')


has= str(name) + '    ' + str(guessesTaken)


f='toplevel.data'
f = open(f, 'wb')
pickle.dump(has, f) # depunem (engl. dump) obiectul în fişier
f.close()
```

I have a problem. If i play again this 'game' toplevel.data will be refresh with new files. I want that if I play again this game toplevel.data won't be refresh with new files.
I want new files be places after old files like:                                         Old files                                                                                  new files(1)                                                                               new files(2)                                                                            new files(3)                                                                             .....................................
Sorry for my english.

Comment: Why do you pickle for saving data here?

Comment: And why don't you overwrite files always? Why don't you append to an existing file?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, you want to write at the end of the file and not at the top.

You can open the file in append mode `a+` or set the file pointer to the end, `f.seek(-1,2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to number the file by counting the existing files:

```
import os, glob

# ...

files = glob.glob('toplevel*.data')
filename = 'toplevel{n}.data'.format(n=len(files))

with open(filename, 'wb') as handle:
  pickle.dump(has, handle) # depunem (engl. dump) obiectul în fişier
```